# Error when plot( ) in for( )

Tags: r, function, for-loop, plot

I got error when using `plot( )` in `for( )`. 
(I tried to reduce workload by using for( ) for repetition)

```
    > head(data.6times[3:7])  #data.6times has 40 columns
 cyear ccode scode country year
    26 1301998   130   ECU Ecuador 1998
    25 1301997   130   ECU Ecuador 1997
    27 1302000   130   ECU Ecuador 2000

    > country.n <- length(data.6times$country) / 6
    > for (i in 1:country.n){
    + aa <- 1+6(i-1)
    + bb <- 6+6(i-1)
    + plot.data <- data.6times[aa:bb,]
    + par(yaxt="n")
    + plot(plot.data$year,plot.data$cluster,ylim=c(0.8, 3.2))
    + text(plot.data$year, plot.data$cluster,labels=plot.data$country, cex=0.6, pos=1, col="blue")
    + text(plot.data$year, plot.data$cluster,labels=plot.data$transition, cex=0.6, pos=3, col="blue")
    + text(plot.data$year, plot.data$cluster,labels=plot.data$prior, cex=0.6, pos=2, col="blue")
    + text(plot.data$year, plot.data$cluster,labels=plot.data$post, cex=0.6, pos=4, col="blue")
    + par(yaxt="s")
    + axis(2, c(1,2,3), c("1","2","3"))
    + filename <- paste(c("/Users/Dropbox/Study/Dissertation/Result_fig/"),c("6times-"),i,c(".jpg"),sep="")
    + dev.copy(jpeg,file=filename,width=1200,height=800)
    + dev.off()
    + } 

    Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

How can I avoid this error?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo/thinko.  `aa <- 1+6(i-1)` should be `aa <- 1+6*(i-1)` (R doesn't treat juxtaposition as multiplication), and similarly for the next line.